# How do I put the output of df.groupby() function in order?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I have written the following piece of code:

```
df.groupby(['neighborhood'])['price'].mean()
```

However, I would like to order the 'price' column from highest to lowest average. How do I do this?

Comment: The output of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is by default sorted by the keys (look at the `sort` argument). Your code returns a Series, so you want to chain on a `.sort_values(ascending=False)`, which sorts output Series by value.

Comment: you need to add sort_values to your code. Here is an example:            df.groupby(['neighborhood']) ['price']. mean().sort_values(ascending=False)